# How to support different handlers for incoming GAE e-mails?

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine, email, python-2.5

In accordance with [GAE docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail), several handlers could be support for incoming e-mails. I would like to support two:

1. *string@appid.appspotmail.com* should go to Handler1;
2. *string+something@appid.appspotmail.com* should go to Handler2;

Looks like I should have something like:

```
- url: /_ah/mail/<???>your_app_id\.appspotmail\.com
  script: handler2.app
  login: admin
- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: handler1.app
  login: admin
```

How the regex (?) should look like to route messages sent to e-mail with plus sign to another handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Updated]**
The following configuration works for me.

```
- url: /_ah/mail/string@.*your_app_id\.appspotmail.com
  script: handler2.app
  login: admin
- url: /_ah/mail/string%2B.*@.*your_app_id\.appspotmail.com
  script: handler1.app
  login: admin
- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: catchall.app
  login: admin
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not mentioning that correctly - by `something` I meant any value.

Comment: Thank you. I got the idea. Looks like first url should be `string@your_app_id\.appspotmail\.com`. Your regex matches values like `string@somethingelse_your_app_id.appspotmail.com`, which I don't need.

Comment: OK, even symbol @ doesn't work. So I've used `%40`. Any idea how to replace `your_app_id` with some variable?