# "POST /_ah/mail/.+" returning 404

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine

I have been reading on stack overflow and but so far I have not found a solution that would work for me. I want to be able to handle incoming email to my app and eventually work with attachments but I am facing an issue.

**app.yaml**

```
application: egg-api
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

builtins:
- remote_api: on

# Activate email receiving

inbound_services:
- mail

# This handler tells app engine how to route requests to a WSGI     application.
- url: .*  # This regex directs all routes to main.app
  script: main.app
- url: /_ah/mail/info@egg-api.appspotmail.com # route everything to handle incoming
  script: handle_incoming_email.app
  login: admin
# Third party libraries
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: lxml
  version: latest
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: MySQLdb
  version: latest
```

**handle_incoming_email.py**

```
import logging
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler
from google.appengine.api import mail


class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, mail_message):
        logging.info("Received a message from: " + mail_message.sender)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True)
```

After starting dev_appserver successfully:
From http://localhost:8000/mail I try to send an email to info@egg-api.appspotmail.com but I get:

```
INFO     2016-04-06 21:31:26,549 module.py:787] default: "POST /_ah/mail/info%40egg-api.appspotmail.com HTTP/1.1" 404 106
```

When I visit http://localhost:8080/_ah/login I have no clue what I am supposed to enter.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the general handler

```
- url: .*
```

to after the specific handler

```
- url: /_ah/mail/info@egg-api.appspotmail.com
```

ie:

```
- url: /_ah/mail/info@egg-api.appspotmail.com # route everything to handle incoming
  script: handle_incoming_email.app
  login: admin
- url: .*  # This regex directs all routes to main.app
  script: main.app
```

Otherwise the general URL rule is applied first, resulting in a 404.

Comment: Thank you Chris, that was it!

Comment: A [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15465283/4058484) configuration will also work.